# Is the handshake_traffic_secret of tls1.3 a symmetric key? If so, why need a master secret?

Tags: tls, authentication

I guess it may be due to man-in-the-middle attack, but are there any other problems? So how does the master secret avoid these problems?

Comment: There is nothing called "pre master secret" in TLS v1.3. There is in TLS v1.2, however. Are you talking about pre master secret in TLS v1.2 or about something else in TLS v1.3?

Comment: @ysdx [https://tls13.ulfheim.net/](https://tls13.ulfheim.net)，on this website it shows four keys, I consider application key is the symmetric key used to communicate. So what does the two handshake key do? Actually I expressed this handshake key, but I don’t know the corresponding name in tls1.3.

Comment: @ysdx May be they are client_handshake_traffic_secret and server_handshake_traffic_secret, I updated the question.